# Using Html.ActionLink in another view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm in Details view of "Group" controller. I want to see the details of the person under that group. When I use this :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details of the Person", "Details", new { id = person.PersonID })
```

It displays the details of the group with that name. When I use this :

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Details of the Person", "Details","Person", new { id = person.PersonID })
```

It displays nothing. How can I write the correct ActionLink to see the details of the Person from Group's view. Thanks.

Comment: In the second snippet, you need to add the parameter for the htmlAttributes - `@Html.ActionLink("Details of the Person", "Details","Person", new { id = person.PersonID }, null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is invoking this overloaded version of the `ActionLink` method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes);
```

I assume in your third argument you meant to pass the controller name but you're currently passing it to the `routeValues` parameter. You probably need this overloaded version:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object htmlAttributes);
```

Then:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details of the Person",
                 "Details",
                 "Person",
                 new { id = person.PersonID },
                 null)
```

Also, you claim that the controller name is actually `Group`, if that's true you need to change the third argument from `"Person"` to `"Group"`.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details of the Person", "Details", "Person", new { id = person.PersonID }, null)
```